# $.ajax + POST + JSON + PHP = why is not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I am now having a problem to send and receive data via $.ajax, json and PHP.

I have my page JQM:

```
<div data-role="page" id="json">

    <div data-role="panel" id="painelMenu">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Voltar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>WGBN Mobile</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Esta é a página 2.</p>
        <p><a href="#painelMenu" data-role="button">painel</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" data-role="button" class="manda">Manda</a></p>
        <hr>
        <div id="mostra"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>&copy; 2013 WGBN Software House.</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

With this JavaScript to run:

```
$(document).delegate("#json", "pageinit", function() {
    $(".manda").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
        url : "json1.php",
        dataType : "json",
        data : '{"opc":"sim"}',
        success : function(data){
            var html = "";

            for($i=0; $i < data.length; $i++){
                html += "<strong>Nome:</strong> "+data[$i].nome +" "+ data[$i].sobreNome;
                html += " <strong>Cidade:</strong> "+data[$i].cidade
                html += "<br />";
            }

            $("#mostra").html(html);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And this PHP script on my server:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['opc'] == "sim"){
        $var = Array(
        array(
            "nome"=>"João",
            "sobreNome"=>"Silva",
            "cidade"=>"Maringá"
        ),
        array(
            "nome"=>"Ana",
            "sobreNome"=>"Rocha",
            "cidade"=>"Londrina"
        ),
        array(
            "nome"=>"Véra",
            "sobreNome"=>"Valério",
            "cidade"=>"Cianorte"
        ));
        echo json_encode($var);
    }
?>
```

But I can not read the data sent to PHP, so it can run code on the server and return a JSON to clinte.

An important detail, if I comment this line in javascrpt:

```
$(document).delegate("#json", "pageinit", function() {
    $(".manda").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
        url : "json1.php",
        dataType : "json",
        /*data : '{"opc":"sim"}',*/
        success : function(data){
            var html = "";

            for($i=0; $i < data.length; $i++){
                html += "<strong>Nome:</strong> "+data[$i].nome +" "+ data[$i].sobreNome;
                html += " <strong>Cidade:</strong> "+data[$i].cidade
                html += "<br />";
            }

            $("#mostra").html(html);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and these lines in PHP:

```
<?php
    //if ($_POST['opc'] == "sim"){
        $var = Array(
        array(
            "nome"=>"João",
            "sobreNome"=>"Silva",
            "cidade"=>"Maringá"
        ),
        array(
            "nome"=>"Ana",
            "sobreNome"=>"Rocha",
            "cidade"=>"Londrina"
        ),
        array(
            "nome"=>"Véra",
            "sobreNome"=>"Valério",
            "cidade"=>"Cianorte"
        ));
        echo json_encode($var);
    //}
?>
```

I have shown in my normal return JQM page.

How do I get PHP to recognize that data sent via JSON?
This is just a test, because solving this I send complete forms for $.ajax to PHP save in the database, the methodological POST in this case is imperative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass an object as parameter, not a string:

```
data : {opc: "sim"},
```

and set type to POST:

```
type: 'post',
```

Comment: Wow, did not believe that was it!
Thank you very much! Thanks @roasted

Answer (score 2):

Try sending your data like this -

```
 data : { opc : 'sim' },
```

and set request type `POST`

```
type: 'post',
```

Comment: Wow, did not believe that was it!
Thank you very much! Thanks @pXl

Answer (score 1):

your missing the `type` attribute. the default type of .ajax is `get`, add `type: 'post'`

```
$.ajax({
        url : "json1.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType : "json",
        data : '{"opc":"sim"}',
        success : function(data){
```

Comment: Wow, did not believe that was it!
Thank you very much!

but also had the problem of how to pass the parameter object.
Other colleagues have responded here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
..
.
.
});
```

You forgot the type. default ajax request is get. But you are checking for POST in php.

Comment: Wow, did not believe that was it!
Thank you very much!

but also had the problem of how to pass the parameter object.
Other colleagues have responded here. Thank you!